# Crontab commands and backup

Tags: backup, cron

I have the following crontab running on my server:

```
0 23 * * * /etc/webmin/postgresql/backup.pl --all
@daily /etc/webmin/fsdump/backup.pl 155931323799484
30 20 * * 0 /etc/webmin/fsdump/backup.pl 157271323799728
```

I know that the 5 values on the left seperated by spaces are the times that the subsequent commands are supposed to run. But what is this "backup.pl" and "--all" and those long strings of numbers? Are those supposed to be commands?

Comment: They look like command line arguments for the backup.pl scripts.

Comment: backup.pl is a pretty generic name. I assumed the code I found is the same as yours. I would suggest checking the snippet below and check if it is the same for yours.Otherwise post the script itself in your question (or the important snippets of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I look at this ( https://github.com/webmin/webmin/blob/master/mysql/backup.pl ):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
# backup.pl
# Called by cron to backup a database, or all databases

$no_acl_check++;
require './mysql-lib.pl';

if ($ARGV[0] eq "--all") {
        $all = 1;
        $cmode = $config{'backup_cmode_'};
        }
else {
        $ARGV[0] || die "Missing database parameter";
        $cmode = 0;
        }
```

I would assume it is the database name.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old fashion of an `/etc/crontab` file:

[image]
<sup>(Source of te mae: http://ltonline.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/2.png)</sup>

So, yes, `/etc/webmin/fsdump/backup.pl` is the command which must to be executed (in this case a perl script called `backup.pl` which is suposed to be located in `/etc/webmin/fsdump/` directory) and `--all`, `155931323799484`, `157271323799728` are arguments for this command. In general, in Linux, any command has arguments which are part of that command.